# Simple HTML parsing with Android?

Tags: android, html, parsing, dom, sax

I have a simple web page I want to scrape with an Android app. [Patterns and Regex are obviously out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) so wondering about a recommendation? SAX, DOM or Jsoup? The HTML I'm working with is only 16K of data so I'd prefer the lightest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think that this is very "general" question and give you completely correct answer it's pretty hard because each developer can give you personal experiences but experiences are very changeable. I have an experience with `DOM` and `JSoup` and both worked as i expected.

I'm using usually `DOM` if i'm working with `XML`. When i'm working with `HTML`(sometimes) i'm using `JSoup` so i can recommend to you JSoup. It makes a trick.

But if you want you can check out

- [`HTMLCleaner`](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) that have good feedbacks
- Or you can check out some [`open-source HTML parsers`](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

### Note:

Difference between `SAX` and `DOM` is that `SAX` parses `XML` when its loading, is faster than `DOM` but has higher demands on application and it's not standart interface for work with `XML` according to [`W3C`](http://www.w3.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I went with Jsoup. It's quite nifty!

Comment: @wufoo you are welcome :) and yes it is. I have only good experiences.